# Error CORS jquery,codeigniter,apache

Tags: php, jquery, apache, codeigniter

Hola tengo una simple aplicacion crud en codeigniter y sql server 2000, en que todas las consultas a la base de datos las hago por medio de jquery ajax. La desarrolle en mi pc local windows 8 con xampp, y todo funciona bien, hasta que quise subir mi aplicacion al servidor, y ahi fue cuando me salio un error y no funciono. 
La consola de chrome dice:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/Retenciones/index.php/Welcome/getMedicos?term=bou. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.149:85' is therefore not allowed access.

Y la de firefox:
Solicitud de origen cruzado bloqueada: La misma política de origen no permite la lectura de recursos remotos en localhost/Retenciones/index.php/Welcome/getMedicos?term=ami. (Razón: Cabecera CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' no presente)

Supongo que estoy infringiendo algo de seguridad pero no se que es.
Intente crear un archivo .htaccess pero el servidor da otro error.

alguna idea para arreglar esto??

gracias

Comment: Busca el error en Google, encontrarás muchos ejemplos y soluciones. Intenta implementar uno de ellos. Y si al hacerlo tienes problemas, presenta tu intento y comenta que error tienes. Así es como funciona esta comunidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estas obteniendo se debe a la configuración de tu servidor, del lado del browser no hay mucho que se pueda hacer, el problema radica en que estás realizando una petición de origen cruzado, es decir que desde un dominio A quieres obtener información del dominio B, lo cual no está permitido, para más información puedes visitar

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Si tienes acceso al servidor y a la configuración del mismo te recomiendo visitar

http://enable-cors.org/

donde encontrarás varias maneras de habilitar CORS en tu servidor.

Comment: gracias !......

Answer (score 0):

Los errores que recibes, son desde tu servidor, son permisos que tu servidor no tiene para que desde otro lugar llames o accedas a esas funciones que localmente si tenias, te dejo un articulo interesante sobre esto

[cross en peticiones ajax](http://cypressnorth.com/programming/cross-domain-ajax-request-with-json-response-for-iefirefoxchrome-safari-jquery/)

Ademas un Link de Stackoverflow con tu mismo problema y su solucion.

[XMLHttpRequest error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160071/xmlhttprequest-cannot-load-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin)

Comment: gracias, me sirvio

Answer (score 0):

Puedes habilitar los CORS del lado de tu SQL SERVER ? si es así debes hacerlo, aunque no se si sea bueno tener el sql conectado directo con la vista